# I have a start_date and end_date. I want to get the list of dates in between GETDATE(). Can anyone help me pointing the mistake in my query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I am getting error in below query.

**Query**

```
;with CTE as 
(select  Dm.Category_id as Category_Label_id,Ca.Category_Name as Category_label_Name,
convert(datetime,  convert(varchar,year(getdate())) + '/' + convert(varchar,MONTH(GETDATE())) + '/' + convert(varchar, day(d.Expiry_Date))) as Exp_date1
,DATEDIFF(day,getdate(), convert(varchar(10),  convert(varchar,year(getdate())) + '/' + convert(varchar,MONTH(GETDATE())) + '/' + convert(varchar, day(d.Expiry_Date))))  as Days_remain
,convert(datetime, DATEADD(day,-Reminder_Days, convert(varchar(10),  convert(varchar,year(getdate())) + '/' + convert(varchar,MONTH(GETDATE())) + '/' + convert(varchar, day(d.Expiry_Date))))) as Exp_date2
from documentalert d 
inner join document dm on dm.doc_id=d.doc_id
inner join Category ca on ca.Category_id = dm.Category_id
inner join category_value c on c.doc_id= dm.doc_id  
inner join dbo.Category_Key k on k.Category_Key_id= c.category_label_id
and c.Category_Label_id=4 -- expiry date
where d.alerttype='M' 
and dm.user_id=427 and dm.is_active=1 )
select * from cte where getdate() between Exp_date2 and Exp_date1
```

**Error**

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 The conversion of a varchar data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Please format your query so we can actually read it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587819/honeybadger please check

Comment: other than that, without some sample data, schema and desired output, it's difficult to see what's going on.

Comment: @Tanner same error persist.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are getting that error as you are building dates by taking the year and month from `GETDATE()` and then appending the day from `Expiry_Date`.

If any of your `Expiry_Date` values have the day as 31, then that will not work in the month of September, which `GETDATE()` will return:

Run the below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
                  CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(GETDATE())) + '/' + 
                  CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(GETDATE())) + '/' + 
                  CONVERT(VARCHAR, 31) -- Fails with 31
              ) AS Exp_date1;
```

Errors with:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Where as this one works:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
                  CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(GETDATE())) + '/' + 
                  CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(GETDATE())) + '/' + 
                  CONVERT(VARCHAR, 30) -- Works with 30
              ) AS Exp_date1;
```

You need to either consider days and month values in your logic or use the `Expiry_Date` in a better way. I'm not sure why you want to append any day value to the current year and month. If you want to filter values to the current month, use a `where` clause to check the value first.